# How to keep train wheels aligned to tracks

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

I am making a simple animation where a train goes on some curved track. I have curved the tracks using a curve and curve modifier and I am animating the train also using a curve and the follow path constraint . I have parented the two bogies to two different empties and the main body to a larger empty with the smaller two empties such that if I move the body then the bogies stay with it and I can also move the bogies individually  . Now when I animate the system using a curve and make the main body follow the path , the wheels get dis-aligned form the tracks so I tried to make the bogies also follow the path using the constraint at same speed but even then they don't stay aligned .

image[image]

In the path constraint I had enabled follow curve and my axis's were correct . Also I had used the same path for the 2 smaller empties.

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file? Also, instead of using so many empties or constraints just use one constraint/empty on the main object and parent the rest of the objects to it.

Comment: Im using only 3 empties, two for the front wheel group and back wheel group. Is there any way to do it with 1 empty? If yes then please tell me how and also I can't upload the  .blend file I can't see any option to do so.

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. also i already saw a question like this is so searching here is also a good idea...

Comment: Yes thank you, I managed to do it. Thought not exactly same but using the offset idea.