# Animating a 3d model in Blender

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender.  I have a model of a Hopper Car used in Model Railroading created in Fusion360.  I would like to have this model follow the rails.  I would like car to be able to follow the curve in the rails left or right and up and down.  Below is what the model looks like.
[image]

The track in front of the car curves right them left.  The Track behind the car curves up and down.  How would I go about animating this in Blender?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: That's not really something a complete beginner to Blender should be attempting. You really want to add a Curve > Path object and get the car to follow that but there aren't any real beginner tutorials showing how to do that.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-train-or-snake-following-path https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truck https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19675/creating-a-trailer-rig https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255896/need-solution-for-train-following-curve-bone-rigging-constraints https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268061/how-to-keep-train-wheels-aligned-to-tracks

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?